# What are the scenario of TestMethod for MVC Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the MVC design pattern. I have started creating test methods for the actions. At current I am creating test methods for the following:

- Test view returned by a controller action to compare the view name.
- Test the View Data returned by a controller action.
- Test whether or not one controller action redirects you to a second controller action.

Is there any other scenario that I should include?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to ask myself the same question and here is what I did:

I am testing the views (not the views data) so testing redirects and view names to me is enough.

If I start testing data then I am expecting certain other parts of the system to return certain data in a certain way (mappers, service layers, repositories). But now I am no longer testing my view I'm testing that my service layer returns certain values and that my mapper correctly maps these values. So I left this to my repository / service tests.

To each his own though - everyone is different.

Answer (score 0):

Nice if you can post the exact action you trying to test. Looks like you have covered most, below are some thoughts you might want to consider.

Yes you would write a Unit Test to compare the View name. If someone change your action to redirect to a different view, you want a test to fail.

Not sure your action returns as RedirectRouteResult or as a ViewResult. I would not write a Unit Test for redirection, unless your action performs a redirection. You would favour testing the current behaviour oppose to what has not been implemented. If your action performs a redirection, then yes you would write a test for that.

If the ActionResult returns a ViewData yes you would write a test make sure the result contains the expected View Data. This is an important test IMO.

If you have repository call or service call within you action you may also write a test to verify the mock/service has been called with the expected parameter. If you are using a isolation framework such as Moq, you can easily set this expectations. Not always but sometimes this may be useful if your action method is trivial.

If you want to be more through, I would also write a test to ensure your action method is decorated with a certain attribute. For example [HttpPost], [HttpGet] or any other attribute you might use.

See my below post should give you some examples.
http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2012/12/04/Simple-test-helper-MVC-Action-has-decorated-with-a-certain-attribute.aspx

Also just to be clear that you would not want to have all these scenarios tested in one Unit Test. They should in separate tests.

What’s important is that looking at the Action and make sure that your tests cover the implemnented behaviour of the Action as much as possible.